# How to properly load lib modules and classes in Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I include a '`lib/`' class or module in my models, Grape API and tests? For example, I have a class:

`ROOT/lib/links/link.rb`

```
module Links
  class Link
    ...
  end
end
```

And I want to include that class in my User model (`app/models/user.rb`), User Grape API (`app/api/v1/users.rb`), and testing suites (`test/models/user_test.rb` and `test/api/v1/users/users_links_test.rb`)

For example, I tried accessing it in my tests through

`link = Links::Link.new(LINK_NAME, LINK_SITE)`

but I get:

`uninitialized constant API::V1::Users::APITest::Links`

I've tried adding this to my `config/application.rb`:

`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**"]`

```
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module ArbitraryAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Auto-load API and its subdirectories
    config.paths.add 'app/api', glob: '**/*.rb'
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/api/*"]
    config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"

    # For Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (rack-cors)
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work. What am I missing? How do I include `lib` files and how should I be calling those classes?

EDIT:
It seems like the only way I can access it is if I do:

`require "#{Rails.root}/lib/links/link"`

Is there a better, more conventional way?

There seems to be another issue, adding `config.autoload_paths << whatever` does not seem to be doing anything. For example, when I `puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` in `rails console`, my changes do not appear.

Comment: is there any error while access?.. if so please add the logs

Comment: often recommended way is to move `lib` folder under `app` directory

Comment: Your problem is your namespacing, you should replace `class Links::Link` with `class Link`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: I've also tried lib/app/links/link.rb but I'm not sure how I include it, any suggestions?

Comment: @PaulHoffer Oops, fixed the namespacing, I figured out to get it working by using a require, is this the only way? Or is there a better convention I'm missing?

Comment: not `lib/app/links/link.rb` but `app/lib/links/link.rb`. Everything under `app` directory is autoloaded.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko sorry, that was a typo, I placed it under `app/lib/links/link.rb` and still get the `uninitialized constant API::V1::Users::APITest::Links` error with `link = Links::Link.new(LINK_NAME, LINK_SITE)`

Comment: @the_basterd I'm sorry I didn't mention it earlier, but your autoload path is wrong. See the answer I provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't resort to using require (if you want to follow Rails conventions). Rails autoloading is based on paths and namespacing, as those two things have to match up. Besides the initial problem with namespacing that was fixed, the way you modify the autoload paths is incorrect. It should be done this way:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

This is if you want to leave `lib/` at the root of your project. As mentioned in the comments, you could move it into your `app/` directory.

Comment: Still doesn't work...does autoload_path only work in production? How about in development and testing?

Comment: Did you move the file back to `#{Rails.root}/lib`?

Comment: Yup, it's under `#{Rails.root}/lib/links/link.rb`

Comment: When I run `puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` in `rails c --sandbox`, it does not show that `lib` is auto loaded

Comment: When I do `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.push "#{Rails.root}/lib"` in the console, I am able to access `Links::Link`, but not when it's specified in my `config/application.rb` file...

Comment: Can you add your `application.yml` to the question?

Comment: I don't have an `application.yml` file

Comment: I'm sorry I meant your `config/application.rb`

Comment: So there's seem to be an issue where I don't think my `application.rb` file is being respected, because I none of the `autoload_paths << whatever` are showing up. Is it because I am not using ActiveRecord (I'm using MongoDB/Mongoid)? I just tested this on a new Rails app w/ ActiveRecord and `puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` shows my changes

Comment: Accepting this as the answer with my answer as the caveat, for anyone who runs into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Paul Hoffer's answer is the accepted answer but for anyone who notices that any changes to `config/application.rb` isn't persisting:

There seems to have been an issue with Spring, where any changes to the `config/application.rb` file wasn't persisting. I had to run `spring stop` to get things to work again. If anyone can explain why this happens sometimes, that'd be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* put your `lib` into `autoload_paths` (as Paul Hoffer suggested), since doing so will prevent it being eager loaded in production (when `config.eager_load = true`).

You will find extensive guide on this topic here: http://hakunin.com/rails3-load-paths